# How do you say that something has "reached beta" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

If I want to describe this site and say that it has reached public beta, how would I say that?

I found ***beta-versio***. Is there another way to say it?

> My attempt:
>
> La retprojekto (aŭ retpaĝo) atingis la publikan beta-version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi dirus "Ĉi tiu retpaĝo atingis la klasifikon publika beta-versio!"

Aŭ, se vi komunikos ĝin per Tviter, ktp

"La retpaĝo ĵus atingis la klasifikon publika beta-versio!"